# How to populate table view with multiple arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to populate a table view with songs, artists and albums. this are in the same table in my sql database but are in different columns. So far I've only got songs but not artists and albums.

```
var searchActive: Bool = false
var search = [Search]()

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:  indexPath)
    
    
    if  (searchActive) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = search[indexPath.row].cleanSong
        cell.textLabel?.text = search[indexPath.row].artists
        cell.textLabel?.text = search[indexPath.row].albums
        
    
       } else {
       searchActive = true
       }
       return cell;
}
```

Comment: You will need different sections to solve this particular problem

Comment: You will have to create data in way that can be displayed in different section. your existing implementation in cell for row method will override the data to the albums.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom UITableViewCell

[Here](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-create-custom-uitableviewcell-f4e69193bab) some tutorial you can try

Answer (score 0):

- Did your **[Search] array** have **artists and albums value**? if not, check how you map those data from the sqldb.
- The way you fill the cell is wrong
  if you call these :

cell.textLabel?.text = search[indexPath.row].cleanSong

cell.textLabel?.text = search[indexPath.row].artists

cell.textLabel?.text = search[indexPath.row].albums

Assuming that cleanSong, artist, and albums values are all exists, then you might end up with your cell showing the "albums" value since it is the last one you set into the cell, if you want to show them all in a cell, you might need a custom cell using XIB.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need custom cells to populate the songs, artists and albums.
You can use multiple `sections` to show different content.

For different section:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 3 // Since you have artist, album and songs content.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // Here you can return different cell as per your section and search result
}
```